# Convert a linked list structure to a binary tree structure with 2 modifications

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, binary-tree

Mention 2 modifications that can be done to a linked list data structure so that it is converted into a binary tree data structure?

Comment: There's not enough context here. What kind of modifications? Are you limited to things that can be done at runtime? Or are you including structural modifications that can be done at the source code level? Or something else?

Comment: I don't know what kind of modifications. I think it's some simple theory but I couldn't understand it. 
I don't need programming but I  need explanation with words how a linked list  data structure can be changed to binary tree.
It's a past paper question.
I don't know how I can explain better.

Comment: which kind of `LinkedList`? singly, doubly or other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather vague, but this is what I think it might mean.

A structure used in a linked list will have a `next` pointer:

```
struct LinkedListNode {
    LinkedListNode *next;
    // data element(s)
};
```

A structure used in a binary tree will have `left` and `right` pointers:

```
struct BinaryTreeNode {
    BinaryTreeNode *left;
    BinaryTreeNode *right;
    // data element(s)
}
```

So, I guess the two modifications the question refers to might be:

1. Change the `next` pointer to a `left` pointer
2. Add a `right` pointer

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the point "2 modification",
but to convert a `LinkedList` to a `BinaryTree`, we can follow two approaches

1. Bottom-up
2. Top-Down

**1) Top-Down approach:**

In this method we can divide the `LinkedList` in two sub lists and middle element will be parent node each
call this recursive method for left and right sub list.

Basic logic behind this can be,

```
ListToBinaryTree(LinkedList list, int start, int end) {

   mid -> start + (end - start) / 2;
   left -> ListToBinaryTree(list, start, mid-1);
   right -> ListToBinaryTree(list, mid+1, end);

}
```

**2) Bottom-Up approach:**

In this approach we will create the child element first and than parent element.

Basic logic behind this can be,

```
ListToBinaryTree(ListNode *& list, int start, int end) {

  mid -> start + (end - start) / 2;
  leftChild -> ListToBinaryTree(list, start, mid-1);
  parent -> new BinaryTree(list -> data);
  parent -> left = leftChild;
  list = list -> next;
  parent -> right = ListToBinaryTree(list, mid+1, end);

}
```

Hope this will be useful.